# Preventing Django table creation from migrations to Readonly Databases

Tags: django

I have a legacy database that I connected my Django app to.  The user I connected to the database only has read access and this holds when trying to make any changes through the Django shell.

My issue lies in the fact that after running my migration, Django created a few tables within the database:

> django_migrations, django_admin_log, auth_group, auth_user, etc

Is there a way to connect to my database so that Django doesnt create these tables?  The only thing I want Django to do is be able to pull information from it, not make any changes.  I am using Django 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use routers: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers

The key is setting the `allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints)` method to return `False`.

Good luck!